# PHP get hard drive in file path

Tags: php

I have an application with an installer that needs to also install a WAMP stack. The user could install anywhere, such as C:\wamp, or D:\foo\wamp.

In one of my app's PHP files, I need to define some directories for other programs. How could I find the absolute path my PHP script is running including the hard drive letter?

Furthermore some Third Party Apps are installed, like FileZilla. IS there a way for me to search for FileZilla.exe or FileZilla path in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` if you want to get the full path of your current script.